# Rails: accessing network.domain.com renders root for domain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dns, routes

I'm trying to set up a subdomain `network` for my domain. In my `config/routes.rb` I have:

```
constraints :subdomain => /network.*/ do
  ...

  # Root
  match '/' => 'questions#index'
  match '' => 'questions#index'
  root :to => 'questions#index', :as => 'network_root'
end

root :to => 'frontend#home'
```

However, sometimes when I access network.domain.com (in production) it shows the root for the whole application (frontend#home). Accessing the subdomain in development works as expected.

EDIT: I've just noticed that requests to the app root (domain.com/) and subdomain root (network.domain.com/) do not get logged in my production.log. Any other page loads work as expected.

Comment: what do you mean with "sometimes"? Can you reproduce the bug? Have you had a look inside the production logs? Are there any errors?

Comment: Sometimes it loads the questions#index, and sometimes it loads frontend#home. There are no errors in the log, and I have the subdomain pointed to the same IP address as the default A record in my DNS